# Rails, odf-report: all images replaced bij same picture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, odf, opendocument

Following the instructions at: [sandrods/odf-report](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report):

In my odt-file I have four mock-images, with four different names (graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4).
In my controller I wish to replace them by four different images:

`r.add_image :graphd1, "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart01.png"`

`r.add_image :graphd2, "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart02.png"`

`r.add_image :graphd3, "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart03.png"`

`r.add_image :graphd4, "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/chart04.png"`

However, the result is that ALL mock-images are replaced by chart04.png?

The images chart01,02,03,04.png are available and are all different.
Is there something I overlooked?
thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I found it: you cannot use the same mock-image more than once (even when they are duplicated versions, with different filenames). I wonder why?